# выдача кода с сервера

Tags: javascript, сервер

Как реализовать выдачу рандомного кода с сервера. То есть при нажатии "получить код" происходила его выдача. Есть код на Javascript, но не знаю как его портировать на сервер. В качестве сервера, локальный компьютер с выделенным ip.

Comment: Добавьте больше объяснения, на чем написан сервер NodeJs, Php, Go и т.д. Добавьте пример кода, который у вас генерирует код. Добавьте пример кода. где есть обработчик кода. Пример кода обработки запроса на сервере.

Comment: Может быть обращение к серверному скрипту? (PHP, JAVA прочее) А он уже вернет вам то, что захотите?

Comment: Во-первых, о каком коде речь? Во-вторых, в чём оказалась проблема запустить на nodejs имеющуюся у вас реализацию?

Comment: $(function() {
  function str_rand() {
    var result = '';
    var words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
    var max_position = words.length - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
      position = Math.floor(Math.random() * max_position);
      result = result + words.substring(position, position + 1);
    }
    return result;
  }

  $("#gen").click(function() {
    $("#short_link").val(str_rand());
  });
});

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label for="first-name">Your code:</label>
  <input type="text" name="code" id="short_link" style="border: 1px solid #3E7EFF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
</li>
<li>
  <div id="gen" style="cursor: pointer" ;>Generate</div>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

[NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/), [express](http://expressjs.com/), за образец взял код из вашего предыдущего вопроса

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const str_rand = () => {
    let result = '';
    const words = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'; 
    while(result.length < 15) result += words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
    return result;
}
app.use('/code', (req, res) => res.end(str_rand()));
app.use('/', (req, res) => res.end(`
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <li>
      <label for="first-name">Your code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="code" id="short_link" style="border: 1px solid #3E7EFF; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;" value="${str_rand()}">
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="gen" style="cursor: pointer" ;>Generate</div>
    </li>   
    <script>    
        $("#gen").click(() => $.get('/code', code => $("#short_link").val(code)));
    </script>
`));
app.listen(8888, () => console.log('Started http://localhost:8888'));
```

Comment: имел ввиду, что нужно чтобы он один код выдавал с сервера рандомно. Не знаете,как это реализовать?